# Teams doesn't display hero image

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've been trying to send cards to Teams channels through a connector. The cards do appear but any hero image I try to send isn't displayed.
The [Message Card Playground](https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/) displays the image correctly but it simply doesn't show up in Teams. I have no issues with the "normal" images.

Here is the JSON that I'm sending through the webhook, but I've also tried the Twitter - Hero image sample card and it doesn't work either :

```
{
  "@type": "MessageCard",
  "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
  "summary": "Hero card testing",
  "title": null,
  "text": null,
  "themeColor": "19b5fe",
  "sections": [
    {
      "title": null,
      "activityImage": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/862653089916096512/ljJwcmFp_bigger.jpg",
      "activityTitle": "Hero image card",
      "activitySubtitle": "This is a test",
      "facts": [],
      "text": null,
      "heroImage": {
        "image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DFv74A0XkAEdwQ_.jpg"
      },
      "images": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Are you by chance able to share the code (i.e. GitHub)? Normally heroImage is in it's own section but this still looks right to me and I'd love to have a working example to debug.

Comment: Here is a small console project that sends three different card designs -- one with a small image, one with a hero image in the same section as the text and one with a second section with just an hero image in it : [link](https://github.com/JamesHyot/TeamsWebhookPusher/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HeroImage is not currently supported in Teams.  This is on the backlog but no ETA at this point.

Comment: Is this still the case as I can not get it to work?

Answer (score 7):

I hit the same problem. It looks like as a sort of workaround you can use the inline image markdown syntax in a non-section's text.

```
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
    "summary": "Summary",
    "title": "Title",
    "text": "![Alt text for the image](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C8NK1XGUIAA-CJK.jpg)",
    "themeColor": "E81123"
}
```

I describe it as a workaround though because the image is not scaled in any way when displayed. As you can see from this example a large image is left very large and overflowing the container.

Comment: Thanks ! Sadly I have no control over the size of my images so I won't be able to use your solution... small images will have to do for now !

Comment: David, where did you find that this markdown is supported by MS Teams? Seriously struggling to find a full list of Markdown support for MessageCard.

Comment: I think at the time I was just trying different common markdown syntax. I don't know if the documentation has improved since then.

Comment: You can also use HTML instead of markdown for a bit more control.

Answer (score 0):

Hero Images ('heroImage') are currently support only in Outlook. Would be available in Teams sometime in future.

[Card with a hero image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9P2T.jpg)

Try the sample Twitter markup for in the card playground: https://aka.ms/messagecardplayground