# HeroImage wornt show in ConnectorCard

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I'm trying to send a Connector Card with the Hero Image tag.

I have followed the examples from the [MessageCard Playground](https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/) 
but even when copying the examples exactly, they will not show either. No errors, the card shows fine, except for the hero image.

The `json` I'm sending:

```json
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
    "summary": "Task 42",
    "title": "Task Done: \"Building the Super Computer\"",
    "sections": [
        {
            "activityTitle": "Mice of Earth",
            "activitySubtitle": "9/13/2016, 11:46am",
            "activityImage": "http://static.website.com/images/smallimage.jpg",
            "facts": [
                {
                    "name": "Team:",
                    "value": "Team-Poster"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Task #:",
                    "value": "42"
                }
            ],
            "text": "Build supercomputer to answer the ultimate question",
            "heroImage": {
                "image": "http://static.website.com/images/party-1644648_1920.jpg",
                "title": "This is the image's alternate text"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

The Outlook Actionable Messages [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/card-reference) also talks about the hero image, but lacks examples.

Comment: I realized that my question is a duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45355198/teams-doesnt-display-hero-image?rq=1
however i cannot mark this myself. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Currently the Hero Image is not supported in Microsoft teams for Connector Cards. You can follow the documentation here :  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/teams-bots-cards and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/connectors, it is clearly stated.

Comment: Would i be able to assume, that it's comming in the future then, as it is mentioned in these other documentations?

Comment: The documentation you linked too was for Outlook Actionable Messages. While Outlook, Teams and Groups all support Connector Cards, they are distinct implementations. Hero Images are supported in Group Connectors and Outlook Actionable Messages, just not Teams.